# Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Tags: android

I have code to make list view like this

```
 class LoadAllProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(allproduct.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        } 

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Cursor cursor;

            int i=0;
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                id_produk[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                String title = cursor.getString(1);
                //String price = cursor.getString(2);
                //String desc = cursor.getString(3);
                //String how_to = cursor.getString(4);
                String time = cursor.getString(5);
                path_image[i] = cursor.getString(7);

                Cursor cur = db.getProductLink(id_produk[i]);
                int y = 0;
                String link = "";
                while(cur.moveToNext()){
                    if(y == 0) link = cur.getString(0);
                    else link = link + "\n" + cur.getString(0);
                    y++;
                }
                product_item[i] = new MenuItem(title, link, time, path_image[i]);
                i++;
                cur.close(); 
            }   

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mainlist.setAdapter(new ListMenuAdapter(product_item));
                }
            }); 
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

and now , I want to show detail of my product with just click selection item of list view with this code

```
 mainlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem


                String pid = productList.get(position).get(TAG_PID);

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),editproductActivity.class);

                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);  
                in.putExtra("phone", mPhoneNumber);
                in.putExtra("daftar", daftar);           
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);    
            }
        });
         }
```

And this log cat show this, and i Think error cause String pid = productList.get(position).get(TAG_PID);

```
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at shoop3.android.edu.allproduct$4.onItemClick(allproduct.java:175)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-06 12:46:25.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can u help me ?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `productList` is empty add data in it, and then check.

```
if(productList.size==0){

   System.out.println("list size is zero...");
   return;

 }
 String pid = productList.get(position).get(TAG_PID);
```

Comment: I think not , because I can show list product , I just cant show the product detail ,

Comment: add data in list.when you iterate cursor

Comment: I add this code

 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
               
               // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
               map.put(TAG_NAME, title);
                
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                 productList.add(map);

Do u know how to add data array , coz my id_product is array , thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your ProductList is empty. Print out its size. It's probably empty hence it's showing that your index is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Check once whether your product list is empty. If so, then it will throw indexoutofbound error.